# Is there a way to add a function to Odoo kanban cards to have the option to open in a new tab (Odoo 10)

Tags: odoo-10

I have a client who loves opening new records in multiple tabs.  Is there a way to modify the kanban open method to include a link to have the option to open in a new tab?

[image: no option to open in new tab]

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I can just wrap some element in an a tag with a custom function to open the record in a new tab. Somewhat of a work around, but I think it will be acceptable for now.

```
<record id="product_template_kanban_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.kanban.custom</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="name" position="after">
                <a name="open_kanban_new_tab" type="object" class="pull-right newtab" help="Open view in a new tab">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-external-link"/>
                    </span>                
                </a>
            </field>
            <xpath expr="//div[1]/div[2]/div[2]" position="after">
                <ul>
                    <li><field name="pc_product_name"/></li>
                </ul>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>



    @api.multi
    def open_kanban_new_tab(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        act_id = self.env.ref('product.product_template_action').id
        menu_id = self.env.ref('pos_custom.custom_search_product_template').id
        return {
            'name': 'Sales Quotation',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'target': 'new',
            'url': '/web?#id=%s&view_type=form&model=product.template&action=%s&menu_id=%s' % (self.id, act_id, menu_id)
        }
```

[image: kanban card with link]